# Where to get access to an inexpensive or free hedge fund/CTA DB?

Tags: historical-data, database, funds

Basically, the question is in the title.

For some similar data: [EDHEC](http://edhec-risk.com) provides some data and one can also get the Mutual Funds data from the Yahoo Finance:is there anything else out there?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want *hedge* funds or *mututal* funds? Those are very different entities.

Comment: As stated in the question I am looking for hedge funds DB.

Comment: Edited to avoid confusion

Comment: Your question body still asks for mutual funds.

Comment: The question is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can get monthly performance for all of the Eurekahedge indices for free from Quandl: http://www.quandl.com/EUREKA-Eurekahedge

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, you will only have access to monthly index numbers or occassional snapshot of manager performance. NilssonHedge (www.nilssonhedge.com) provides a free CTA/Managed Futures database. For browsing quant funds, this might be a good suggestion. I'm affiliated with the site.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the free to access database from [www.bankacareer.com](http://www.bankacareer.com) it actually provides up to 25k funds at the moment. You can sort it by Type (hedge fund, mutual, etc), Strategy (Income, Growth, etc) and even by country and city.
Enjoy!

Comment: You need to disclose your affiliation with anything you're advertising here.